# Using Nokogiri to scrape groupon deal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nokogiri

I'm following the [Nokogiri railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/190-screen-scraping-with-nokogiri?view=asciicast) to write a scraper for Groupon. I keep on getting the following error when I run my rb file.

```
Flamingo Conference Resort and Spa Deal of the Day | Groupon Napa / Sonoma
traveldeal_scrape.rb:9:in `block in <main>': undefined method `text' for 
nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Here is my scrape file.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

url = "http://www.groupon.com/deals/ga-flamingo-conferences-resort-spa?c=all&p=0"
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
puts doc.at_css("#content//h2/a").text

title = doc.at_css("#content//h2/a").text
price = doc.at_css("#amount").text[/[0-9\.]+/]
puts "#{title} - #{price}"
puts doc.at_css(".deal")[:href]
```

EDITED: Code above now works!

I used the exact same rubular expression as the tutorial. I am also unsure of whether or not my CSS tags are correct. Thanks!

Comment: perhaps you've already switched. But, if you're still working on it: you know Groupon has a nice API right? https://sites.google.com/site/grouponapiv2/home

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've got an oversight:

```
doc.css(".deal").each do |deal|
  title = item.at_css("#content//a").text
  price = item.at_css("#amount").text[/\[0-9\.]+/]
  puts "#{title} - #{price}"
  puts item.at_css(".deal")[:href]
end
```

Should be:

```
doc.css(".deal").each do |deal|
  title = deal.at_css("#content//a").text
  price = deal.at_css("#amount").text[/\[0-9\.]+/]
  puts "#{title} - #{price}"
  puts deal.at_css(".deal")[:href]
end
```

Comment: Thanks, melee. Fixed it and made the changes to my code above. Getting an undefined method 'text' for nil:Nil Class (NoMethodError) now.

Also, the rubular expression warning is still there. Can this be ignored?

Comment: Well, I threw this into `irb` and ran `doc.css(".deal").first.title`, which threw the error - what is being returned doesn't have a title. I'm having a hard time inspecting the XML, but I'll see what I can come up with for you.

Comment: Mine prints the title string correctly if I use `puts doc.at_css("#content//h2/a").text`

Comment: @hyngn I'm getting nil on that, but you can adjust the code above with that and you should be good to go. Actually, you might not need a block here, because it looks like it only returns one deal, is that correct?

Comment: Correct, but I don't think the block matters. It will just run through the loop once in this case, right?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your regular expression is that it's missing the dollar sign you're trying to escape: `.text[/\$[0-9\.]+/]`

Comment: Thanks, michaelmichael. That fixed the warning.